# We can't find products matching the selection. error in megento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm using magento2 shopping website and I'm trying to upload some products and during that I'm getting "We can't find products matching the selection." on front each category and product page.

I'm trying to solve that issue but no success, anybody here to give me the best suggestion how to fix that or what command use to fix the issue.

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4049498/558ab4e971f1460f663d134cb64ca907

Comment: I solved the issue, just follow these command...
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 0):

Every time you add/edit/remove products, you need to perform a reindex.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

After re-indexing, everything should work now as intended.

Comment: lol no, you don't have to do this. Usually the index is getting refreshed automatically on save or via cronjobs.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime you restart your computer, elasticsearch not start, try this command:a

systemctl start elasticsearch.service

php bin/magento cache:flusha

and then reload your page